# nodejs mssql return recordset

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, node-mssql

Im trying to past the recordset from mssql request.query like a return value.
Following the code on https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql is easy to make a a console output but when I try to asign the recordset to another variable doesnt work. What Im doing wrong?

```js
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'XXXXXX',
    server: '192.168.8.25',
    database: '3TWIMDB',
}
var resultado='';
sql.connect(config, function(err){
var request = new sql.Request();
  request.query('select 1 as VehiCLASS',function(err,recordset){
    console.log(recordset[0].VehiCLASS);
    resultado = recordset[0].VehiCLASS;
  });
  sql.close();
});
console.log("rsul: "+resultado);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The query is run asynchronously.  `console.log` actually runs before `resultado = recordset[0].VehiCLASS` completes, so it's not set.

You must synchronize any code that relies on asynchronous operations. You have to do this by using the callbacks:

```
resultado = recordset[0].VehiCLASS;
console.log("rsul: ", resultado);
```

You may also specify your own callback function to prevent nesting:

```
function queryComplete(err, result) {
    // should handle error

    console.log("rsul: ", result);
}

resultado = recordset[0].VehiCLASS;
queryComplete(null, resultado);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement it. And the code in mssql npm has changed since. I would like to be able to save the query result to a variable and I have the same problem. Please help !

Comment: the end result for me would be to use express and save 2 or more queries to variables and do "app.get(website,{query1=query1,query2=query2})"